# Pass a List to another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

I wanted to pass a List type object which is in the main JPS to an include JSP ( jsp:include). Since the parm only support strings, I cannot use the parm tag to pass List type data to the include file.

Uses examples:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="applications" value="${applications}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Or:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="applications" value="${confirmed_applications}"/>
</jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="applications" value="${unconfirmed_applications}"/>
</jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="applications" value="${canceled_applications}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

I could create a Simple Tag Handler but I would like to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 10):

Agree with ChssPly76 that its probably a sign of trouble if the List is being generated in the JSP, but another alternate approach to get the object to the other JSP is to add it to the HttpServletRequest objects attribute field using a scriplet:

JSP with the List:

```
<%
request.setAttribute("theList", ListObject);
%>
```

The other JSP:

```
<%
List myList = (List) request.getAttribute("theList");
%>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed what jsp tags are meant for. You create a .tag file that accepts *attributes* (not parameters), which can be of arbitrary type.

See [this article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/12/jsp2part4.html) for a good tutorial.

"Params" are analogous to the parameters you see in an HTTP query (the part of the URL following the '?').

Comment: I didn't knew one could create taglibs in pure JSP. Great, man! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works great. Small note: The important part is setting the **type** of the attribute as Object otherwise it will be treated as String. `<%@ attribute name="answers" required="true" type="java.lang.Object" %>`

Answer (score 3):

How are you obtaining that list in your main JSP?

If you're getting it from the model (direct / indirect request / session attribute) you can pass the **name** of the attribute to your included JSP and re-obtain it from model there:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="applications" value="confirmedApplications"/>
</jsp:include>
```

If you're generating or modifying that list in the JSP itself you've really got bigger problems then this :-) but you can **bind** your list to request under some attribute name and then use the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you put the list in request scope and using `applications` as the name of your parameter you can refer to the list like this `${requestScope[param.applications]}`

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the List object via the requestScope :

```
<c:set var="listApplications" value="${applications}" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/appList.jsp" />
```

And in appList.jsp you can retrieve the list using

```
${requestScope.listApplications}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use request or session objects for transferring objects.

Advantage

Request - Use request as its lifetime is lesser compared to a session object.

Session - You can retrieve the same object sometime later in another page or action

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have parent.jsp and child.jsp.

You want to:

1) Include child.jsp from parent.jsp,
2) Send some parameters from parent.jsp to the child.jsp.

Do the following steps:

1) In parent.jsp
`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:set var="items" value="${itemsFromDB}" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="child.jsp"/>
```

`
2) In child.jsp

```
<div>
alert("${requestScope.items}");
</div>
```

Thats all.