# Writing multiple images to byteArrayOutputstream

Tags: java, java-io

I've a requirement to add multiple images to a output stream and  display those images in JSF.

Ex code:

```
List<inputStream> images = list of inputstream - each image is one input stream

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
for(inputStream iStream: images){
    stream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(iStream);
}
return stream.toByteArray();
```

Now it is displaying only first Image but not displaying remaining images.

Please help me here to get pass multiple images and display in jsp.

Comment: you need `ByteArrayOutputStream` list as well

Comment: ah I mean `byte[]` list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
List<byte[]> imagesByteList = new List<byte[]>;
for(inputStream iStream: images){
    stream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(iStream);     
    imagesByteList.add(stream.toByteArray());
    stream.reset();
}
return imagesByteList; // here you get all your image in bytes array form
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...so it is returning list of byte[]..in my JSP i've to iterate and display it? but I should have only one link in my JSP which should display all the images by clicking on single link

Comment: Yes. I guess it is not a problem right? you can handle the iteration on page load

Comment: But These images are check front and back side..so clicking on single link have to show two images...

Comment: urmm, I don't get it.

Comment: Since it is a list..I've to iterate in that case each image will have single link but i want to display all the images upon clicking on single link.

Comment: I guess you can use a single link to pass the list of images. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538821/pass-a-list-to-another-jsp-file)